# What should be included in sequelize migrations?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, database-migration

*First time I encounter `Sequelize migrations`, I have confusion about what I **should & shouldn't** include in the migrations file. Unfortunately wasn't able to find any guide or reference not even in docs.*

columns names and their properties are obviously written in the migrations file.

**Should we include associations, model level methods, getters & setters, and virtual?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is clearly described in the question itself. It means DO and DON'Ts of Sequelize migrations file. I had this issue while using migrations for the first time, wasn't able to find help anywhere, so i wrote this for people who are just getting into sequelize migrations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the starting point for those getting into `sequelize` `migrations` & wanna know **DO and DON'Ts** of sequelize migrations.

Rule of thumb is , whatever go in database should be included in migrations files.

**Only** column names their properties (type etc) should go under sequelize migrations files.

**Excluded from migrations**

these shouldn't be included in migrations files.

- getters
- setters
- associations
- virtual fields
- model methods

**above fields don't actually exist in database, rather dynamically generated so those shouldn't be included in migrations file.**